# Не удаляется добавляемый виджет Entry в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так, чтобы удалялись добавляемые Entry, а не уже имеющийся?

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")

def addFlat():
    kom_kv1=Entry(root)
    kom_kv1.grid()

def deleteFlat():

    kom_kv1.grid_forget()

kom_kv1=Entry(root)
kom_kv1.grid() 
plus=Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat)
plus.grid()

plus2=Button(root,text='Удалить квартиру', command=deleteFlat)
plus2.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись в переменную `kom_kv1` внутри функции создает новую локальную переменную и не меняет значение глобальной переменной с именем `kom_kv1` снаружи функции. Если нужно записать из функции в глобальную переменную, нужно явно указать, что вы хотите использовать глобальную переменную:

```
def addFlat():
    global kom_kv1
    kom_kv1=Entry(root)
    kom_kv1.grid()
```

Если нужна возможность последовательно удалять добавленные элементы, нужно помнить их все, а не только один. И еще нужно договориться, удаляем начиная с самого старого  или с самого нового ([FIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) или [LIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO)).

Допустим это будет FIFO (т.е. очередь - первый добавленный будет удален первым). В качестве хранилища используем обычный список.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")

flats = []
counter = 1

def addFlat():
    global counter
    kom_kv = Entry(root)
    kom_kv.grid()
    # Для наглядности в текстовое поле записываем его номер по порядку:
    kom_kv.insert(0, str(counter))
    counter += 1
    flats.append(kom_kv)

def deleteFlat():
    if flats: # Если список не пустой
        # Достаем из начала списка один элемент, и сразу удаляем из окна
        flats.pop(0).grid_forget()
        # Если нужно удалять начиная с последнего добавленного, то меняем на такую строку:
        # flats.pop().grid_forget()

plus=Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat)
plus.grid()

plus2=Button(root,text='Удалить квартиру', command=deleteFlat)
plus2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Кстати, для удаления лучше использовать не `grid_forget`, а `destroy`, иначе все "удаленные" элементы управления так и будут висеть в памяти, хотя на экране отображаться не будут. `grid_forget` нужен для временного скрытия элемента, чтобы его потом можно было снова отобразить при помощи метода `grid`.

Comment: Спасибо большое， код начал удалять， но почему то не все вновь добавленные， а только последнее добавленное， а подскажите пожалуйста， как удалить последовательно асе добавленное?

Comment: Добавил пример с возможностью последовательного удаления всех ранее добавленных элементов.

Comment: Спасибо!!! очень помогли =) хорошо объяснили!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть вариант элегантнее записать нижеследующий код?

Comment: Вообще лучше отдельным вопросом, вопросы в ответах не приветствуются. 1 - можно один список использовать для всего, внутри хранить набор словарей или своих объектов. 2 - для ввода достаточно одного набора редактируемых полей, для вывода можно использовать listbox или treeview. 3 - если списки всегда одного размера, достаточно проверять на пустоту только один из них. И обратите внимание, у меня идет не сравнение с нулем (это условие всегда будет ложным, список никогда не будет равен нулю), а просто `if flats`.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!! Но не поняла на счет 2 пункта，как использовать listbox для рационализации в моем случае

Comment: Я имею в виду вводить данные через фиксированное количество текстовых полей (допустим, 4 поля), а выводить все квартиры через listbox или табличку в treeview.

Comment: Можете задать отдельный вопрос с вашим кодом и меткой инспекция-кода, я отвечу с примером

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")

flats = []
flats1 = []
flats2 = []
flats3 = []



def addFlat():


    kom_kv=Label(root,text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
    kom_kv.grid()
    kom_kv1=Entry(root)
    kom_kv1.grid()
    sobs=Label(root,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
    sobs.grid()
    sobs1=Entry(root)
    sobs1.grid()

    flats.append(kom_kv)
    flats1.append(kom_kv1)
    flats2.append(sobs)
    flats3.append(sobs1)

def deleteFlat():
    if flats!=0 and flats1!=0 and flats2!=0 and flats!=0: 
        flats.pop().grid_forget()
        flats1.pop().grid_forget()
        flats2.pop().grid_forget()
        flats3.pop().grid_forget()

plus=Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat)
plus.grid()

plus2=Button(root,text='Удалить квартиру', command=deleteFlat)
plus2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```