# Как создавать поля для ввода (Entry), при нажатии на кнопку (Add_field)?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как я могу добавлять поля ввода пользователя (Entry) при нажатии на кнопку "Add link", и удалять поле с конца, при нажатии на кнопку "Remove link"?
Создал пустой список для сохранения введенной информации, для того чтобы использовать ее дальше в коде. Удаление и добавление элементов происходит, проблема с полями ввода.. Спасибо

```py
def clicked():
    links_info = tkr.Label(window, text="Each given node must have at least one link\nfor example: (a, b, c), c - is optional argument.", font=("Arial", 8))
    links_info.grid(column=0, row=3)
    btn_add = tkr.Button(window, text="Add link", bg='#0269A1', fg="#ffffff", command=add_entry_field)
    btn_add.grid(column=1, row=3)
    btn_remove = tkr.Button(window, text="Remove link", bg='#0269A1', fg="#ffffff", command=remove_entry_field)
    btn_remove.grid(column=1, row=4)

def add_entry_field():
    entryWidgets.append(tkr.Entry())
    entryWidgets[-1].grid(column=0, row=4)
    print(entryWidgets)

def remove_entry_field():
    try:
        entryWidgets.pop()
    except IndexError as err:
        print("List is empty: ", err)
    print(entryWidgets)

btn = tkr.Button(window, text="Continue", bg='#0269A1', fg="#ffffff", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Не удаляется добавляемый виджет Entry в Tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/958605/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Текстовые поля нужно добавлять в разные ячейки `grid` (при добавлении в одну ячейку они просто заменяют друг друга):

   ```
   def add_entry_field():
       entryWidgets.append(tkr.Entry())
       # Номер колонки определяется по количеству элементов в списке:
       entryWidgets[-1].grid(column=len(entryWidgets), row=4)  
       print(entryWidgets)
   ```
2. При удалении нужно вызывать метод удаления элемента управления из `grid` (`grid_forget`) или уничтожения элемента управления (`destroy`):

   ```
   def remove_entry_field():
       try:
           # pop() возвращает удаленный из списка элемент, к этому элементу применяем нужный метод
           entryWidgets.pop().grid_forget()  # Или entryWidgets.pop().destroy()
       except IndexError as err:
           print("List is empty: ", err)
       print(entryWidgets)
   ```

Comment: Подобную информацию нашел, все получилось, спасибо)

Comment: @R.Batyrshin, если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как принятый - поставить галку слева от ответа.

Comment: все исправил, простите не часто тут спрашивал) Спасибо